# How can I get a working git repository back?

Tags: git

We have been working on a git repository since a few month. I do not know is this information will be useful, but this repository contains a lot of 3D assets and is therefore quite huge: the remote repository weights more than 20GB. What I do know is that such a heavy repository is a mistake.

Cloning it gives me only a empty repository, with the following warning: `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

On the newly cloned local repository, the `git branch -a`commands return nothing. The `git log`commands returns the following error `fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet` despite the fact that there are several branches on this repository.

Those two command returns the same results on the remote repository.

How can I get a working repository back from the cloned one or from the remote one?

Comment: Are you sure you used the right address when you git cloned?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure: I have cloned anew several times, using git command lines and a GUI tool. I get the same errors in the remote repository, so I am quite sure this an error within the repository itself.